# Why in DCT (V = C * U * C^T) C comes before C^T, but in IDCT (U = C^T * V * C) C^T comes before C?

Tags: dct

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD3YZ.png)Why in DCT (V = C * U * C^T)  C comes before C^T, but in IDCT (U = C^T * V * C) C^T comes before C?
I am very happy if there is an answer.

Comment: The precedence of `^` is higher than the precedence of `*`, so `C^T` comes before all the rest in both cases.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb thanks for your help, but in my question, C^T is transpose matrix of C.

Comment: do u have any other ideas with this problem? please help me if u can TT_TT

Comment: Sure, but you do understand that operations have precedences, right? The precedence of `^` is either higher or lower than the precedence of `*`, hence `C^T` is always executed either before or after all the other operations.

Comment: P.S.: My argument above wouldn't hold for `*` and `/`, for example. But the case of `*` and `^` is different.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb ^^ thank youuuu, i appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C is an orthonormal matrix, therefore CC<sup>T</sup> = C<sup>T</sup>C = I.

If V = C U C<sup>T</sup>, then C<sup>T</sup> V C = C<sup>T</sup> C U C<sup>T</sup> C = I U I = U, so that is the way the calculate U back from V.

You can see that by swapping around whether the C<sup>T</sup> is to the left or to the right, after substituting the definition of V in, C and C<sup>T</sup> end up together on both sides. Without swapping them around, C would end up with C, and C<sup>T</sup> would end up with C<sup>T</sup>, then they do not cancel out. In other words: taking the DCT of a DCT does not bring you back to the start.

Which one of these is considered the DCT and which the IDCT is a matter of convention, it works either way.